How do Quinian ur-elements compare to Lawverian abstract sets?
Basically, although ZFC is typically the norm in modern mathematical practice (I am told), there are also well-known issues that suggest it may have its own expiration date.
I did not see the proof, but apparently, according to how numbers are defined in ZFC, 3 ∈ π. Now, one can either accept this as an “interesting result”, or, reject it as, as I saw one person call it, a “junk theorem”, indicating that ZFC is not a perfect model of what we want it to be, that is, the world of logical truth, the concept of number, etc.
That idea has come up so regularly in my thinking of late that I wonder if there is a philosophical name for it. It is a type of abductive reasoning where we modify premises to attain conclusions, then modify conclusions to attain different premises. Specifically in math, it is this question of to what extent a formal system actually proves anything about “our world”, if we are at license to reject or tweak it the moment we find it proves something we find untenable.
Anyway, it is also known that “pure” set theory, like ZFC, is awkward for modeling “collections of things” - even though this is what it is heavily used for, especially in philosophy and related scientific disciplines. ZFC begins with a single primitive “object” or “element” - the empty set - and all other sets are nested collections of sets containing other sets. This is why such a set theory is called “pure”.
I do not know the full history of abstract sets, but I know at some point Lawvere (who I hold in extremely high regard) took issue with set theory as it was, and developed a modification of his category-theoretic axioms for mathematics which specifically described the category of sets. This theory is called the elementary theory of the category of sets. An introduction to it can be found here.
I have not yet found the time to study the ETCS, but I was under the impression it at least implied the existence of “abstract elements”; helping the philosophically inclined be able to use set theory and logic to talk about “collections of things”, without the odd addendum that by “Tom Cruise is an element in the set of actors” we actually are representing “Tom Cruise” with a particular set like “{{{}},{{},{{}}}}”.
ETCS is commonly referred to as a “structural” set theory. This makes sense to me intuitively, since the category of sets expresses various relations between sets without ever making explicit each set-object’s internal structure.
I know Quine’s new foundations has a concept of an “urelement”. Defined as there being “multiple distinct empty sets”, I think these empty sets act like “abstract objects”.
I am wondering how ETCS and QNF compare. Do they both have abstract elements? Does QNF solve “denotational” issues of ZFC as ETCS does? Do they generate different universes of sets from each other?

How do I put this delicately? This question seems to come from someone who is just learning about set theory and foundational mathematics and doesn't yet really grasp what is going on. On the one hand, I don't want to discourage your exploration, but on the other, this question contains some odd ideas about the role of set theory, how it relates to arithmetic and similar, and I hate to leave these misunderstandings in place to potentially confuse others. You and the group would be better served if you would ask shorter questions with less extraneous (and incorrect) detail.

Both still based on FOL, as general flavors to be tasted ETCS is structurally categorical thus mathematical to avoid certain complexities associated with axiom of choice and the cumulative hierarchy, while QNF is metaphysical to mainly materially address comprehension paradoxes...
